# How to find multicast sender address in asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, multicast

I'd like to know, how to determine IP address of machine, which sends multicast packets to the multicast group, using asio library. Now my source is like:

```
std::string listen_addr4 = lpd_config.config.lpd_listen_host4();
std::string multicast_addr4 = lpd_config.config.lpd_multicast_host4();
short multicast_port = lpd_config.config.lpd_multicast_port();

asio::ip::udp::endpoint lpd_listen_endpoint4(asio::ip::address::from_string(listen_addr4), multicast_port); //TODO ipv6 support

asio::ip::udp::socket lpd_listen_socket4(lpd_io_service, lpd_listen_endpoint4.protocol());  //TODO ipv6 support

lpd_listen_socket4.set_option(asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
lpd_listen_socket4.bind(lpd_listen_endpoint4);  //TODO ipv6 support

lpd_listen_socket4.set_option(asio::ip::multicast::join_group(asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_addr4)));    //TODO ipv6 support
```

What to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As any machine could be broadcasting to the multicast group, what you need to do is to start listening to messages, using the [receive_from](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive_from.html) or the [async_receive_from](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from.html) methods on the upd::socket object.

These methods will populate an endpoint object with the remote peer details, which you can then resolve to an address.

Comment: Thank you, very much! It's not very intuitive, that listen endpoint address is changed to sender's address.